# CRUD web no se actualiza en Java

Tags: java, servlets, crud

Estoy aprendiendo Servlets y JSP con MVC (Java) usando como servidor  Tomcat v 9.0 . La tarea es hacer un CRUD.  El problema es que a veces tarda muchísimo en actualizar la versión cada vez que hago un cambio.Incluso dandole muchas veces al botón de run en Eclipse.

He implementado cambiar las labels para asegurarme de que se está corriendo la nueva versión pero luego me di cuenta que a veces ciertas clases no se actualizan mientras que otras si con lo cual el método me falla. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se actualice mas rápido?

Me han dicho que hay que borrar la carpeta Target que yo no tengo. Investigando creo haber entendido que solo se genera si se usa Maven, cosa que por el momento no estoy usando en el curso. ¿Cómo puedo logarlo sin implementar esta herramienta?

también me hablaron de un archivo "war" que tampoco tengo. Puede parecer un problema tonto pero me ha dado muchos dolores de cabeza haciendome creer que había errores en el código ya que ni reiniciando el servidor y actualizando muchas veces se solucionaba.

Dejo el código aunque no creo que sea relevante . Aclaro que faltaría el codigo para actualizar y borrar. Por ahora solo muestra la BDD. Aclaro que el programa funciona PERFECTO no estoy preguntando por errores en el código. Sólo por el método de actualización cada vez que se da click a Run

ESTE ES EL CONTROLADOR DESDE DONDE ARRANCA EL PROGRAMA POR init()

```
package com.pildorasinformaticas.productos;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControladorArticulos
 */
@WebServlet("/ControladorArticulos")
public class ControladorArticulos extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private ModeloArticulos modeloarticulos;
    
    @Resource (name = "jdbc/Productos")
    private DataSource miPool; 
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        
        try {
            modeloarticulos = new ModeloArticulos(miPool);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    
                    
        String comando = request.getParameter("instruccion");
        if (comando == null) 
            comando = "listar";
    
        switch (comando) {
        
        case "listar":  
            
            listar(request , response );
            
            break;
            
        case "insertarbbdd": 
        
            System.out.println("alla");
        insertar(request,response);
                    
        break;
        }
        
    }

    
    private void insertar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        
        String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcion");
        int codigo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codigo")) ;
        float precio = Float.parseFloat (request.getParameter("precio"));
        Articulos articulo = new Articulos ( codigo, descripcion ,  precio);
        modeloarticulos.agregarArticulo(articulo);
        listar(request , response );
    
    }

    private void listar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        List<Articulos> listaArticulos ;
        
        try {
            
            listaArticulos = modeloarticulos.getArticulos();
            request.setAttribute("LISTAARTICULOS", listaArticulos);
            RequestDispatcher miDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ListaArticulos.jsp");
            miDispatcher.forward(request, response);        
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }

}
```

ESTA ES LA INTERFAZ QUE OFRECE AL USUARIO AGREGAR ELEMENTOS A LA BD O VOLVER A VISUALIZARLA ENTERA

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link href="estiloposta.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <h1>Registrar una entrada nueva</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside>
     
    </aside>
    <form name="form1" method="get"  action="ControladorArticulos">
    <input type="hidden" name="instruccion" value="insertarbbdd">
    <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="elemento">
        <label> Desca </label>  
        <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" required />
      </div>

      <div class="elemento">
        <label> Codigoss </label>
        <input type="number" id="codigo" name="codigo" required min="1" />
      </div>

      <div class="elemento">
        <label> Precios </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="precio"
          name="precio"
          required
          step="0.01"
          min="0.01"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="elemento"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar"/></div>
   </form>
       <form name="form2" method="get"  action="ControladorArticulos">
    
      <div class="elemento"><input type="submit" id="volver" value="Volver a la BDDaa" /></div>
          
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ESTA ES LA CLASE DEL MODELO

```
package com.pildorasinformaticas.productos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ModeloArticulos {

    private DataSource pool;

    public ModeloArticulos(DataSource pool) {
        
        this.pool = pool;
    }
    
    public List<Articulos> getArticulos() throws Exception {
        
        List<Articulos> miLista = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Connection conexion = pool.getConnection();
        
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos";
        Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet miResultSet = miStatement.executeQuery(sql);
        
        while (miResultSet.next()) {
            
            int codigo = miResultSet.getInt("codigo");
            String descripcion = miResultSet.getString("descripcion");
            float precio = miResultSet.getFloat("precio");
            
            Articulos temporal = new Articulos(codigo,descripcion,precio);
            miLista.add(temporal);
            
        }
        
        return miLista;
    }

    public void agregarArticulo(Articulos articulo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }   
}
```

ESTA ES LA CLASE QUE LISTA TODA LA BASE DE DATOS (.HTML)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix ="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<style type="text/css">
       .cabecera {

   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;                  
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #08088A;  
}


 .filas{
 
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #5882FA;

 }


table {

float : left;
}

#ContenedorBoton {

margin-left: 1000 px

}

</style>

</head>

<table>

<tr><td class = "cabecera">codigo</td><td class = "cabecera">descripcion</td>
<td class = "cabecera">precio</td></tr>

<c:forEach var= "tempArt" items = "${LISTAARTICULOS}"> 

<tr> 
<td class = "filas">${tempArt.codigo}</td>
<td class = "filas">${tempArt.descripcion}</td>
<td class = "filas">${tempArt.precio}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>



</table>

<div id = "contenedorBoton">
<input type="button" value="Insertar Registro" onclick= "window.location.href='formularioregistro.html'"/>
</div>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO XML CON LA CONFIGURACIÓN DEL POOL DE CONEXIONES

```
<Context>

<Resource name = "jdbc/Productos" auth = "Container" type = "javax.sql.DataSource"

          maxActive= "15"  maxIdle = "3"  maxWait = "5000" 
          
          username = "root"  password = ""
          
                    driverClassName ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          
          url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd1"   >

</Resource>

</Context>
```

ESTA ES LA CLASE PRODUCTOS QUE REPRESENTA CADA OBJETO DE LA BASE DE DATOS

```
package com.pildorasinformaticas.productos;

public class Articulos {

private int codigo;
private String descripcion;
private float precio;
        
    public Articulos(int codigo, String descripcion, float precio) {
        
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    public Articulos(String descripcion, float precio) {
        
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Articulos [codigo=" + codigo + ", descripción=" + descripcion + ", precio=" + precio + "]";
    }
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public float getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }
    public void setPrecio(float precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas que el código, nos sirve conocer de la configuración de tu servidor de aplicaciones; puedes comenzar por ¿cuál servidor usas?.

Comment: gracias por responder. Tomcat v 9.0

Comment: Considera que si hay un error -que no le gustó al servidor- es muy probable que tu aplicación no se actualice. En la pestaña servidores, observa el estado del servidor entre los corchetes después de su nombre, principalmente la segunda palabra que debe indicar sincronización. Revisa el log del servidor.